# MVVM enable/disable button with a converter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ivalueconverter

i have 2 buttons that i want to disable/enable based on a counter

here is my counter

```
private int _stepCounter = 0;
        public int StepCounter
        {
            get { return _stepCounter; }
            set{_stepCounter=value; OnPropertyChanged("StepCounter");}
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

i have written the following IValueConverter

```
 [ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(bool))]
    class inttobool : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture, string ButtonName)
        {
            int stepcount = (int)value;
            if (stepcount == 0 && ButtonName == "PreviousStepButton")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (stepcount == 5 && ButtonName == "NextStepButton")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture, string Buttonname)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and my buttons looks like the follwing

```
<Button Name="NextStepButton" Content="Next Step" Click="NextStepButton_Click" />
<Button Name="PreviousStepButton" Content="PreviousStep"click="PreviousStepButton_Click" />
```

`NextStepButton_Click` event increases the counter by one
`PreviousStepButton_Click` event decreases the counter by one

i am trying to learn mvvm and my question is how do i send the name of the button that i clicked to the converter?

what should the binding statement in the IsEnabled property in XAML look like?

i need to disable the `NextStepButton` when the counter gets to 5
and i need to disable the `PreviousStep` when the counter gets to 0
other wise both are enabled.

Comment: Are you following MVVM? I don't think so,

Comment: @FaisalHafeez not totally!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i am trying to learn mvvm

MVVM approach assumes, that you should use commands (any [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx) implementation), when you want to perform any action in your view model, and bind these commands to buttons:

```
<Button Content="Previous" Command="{Binding PreviousCommand}"/>
<Button Content="Next" Command="{Binding NextCommand}"/>
```

Usually, `ICommand` implementations are `RelayCommand`/`DelegateCommand` (google it). These implementations allow you to define two delegates in your view model:

- the first one is a command payload, an action itself.
- the second one is a checking for ability to perform that action.

WPF buttons are familiar with `ICommand`, so, if the command is bound to button, button calls `CanExecute`, and if it returns `false`, the button becomes disabled.

There's no need for converter here (and, of course, for any `button_Click` handlers).
You even don't need any `IsNextEnabled`/`IsPreviousEnabled` properties - binding and `CanExecute` do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for doing this using MVVM.

View:

```
<Button Content="Next Step Button" IsEnabled="{Binding NextStepButtonEnabled}" Command="{Binding NextStepButtonCommand}" />
<Button Content="Previous Step Button" IsEnabled="{Binding PreviousStepButtonEnabled}" Command="{Binding PreviousStepButtonCommand}" />
```

ViewModel

```
// Binding Command.
private ICommand _nextStepButtonCommand;
public ICommand NextStepButtonCommand
{
    get { return _nextStepButtonCommand?? (_nextStepButtonCommand= new RelayCommand(NextStepButton);}
}

// Button Action
public void NextStepButton()
{
   _stepCounter++;
}

// Button enabled check,
public bool NextStepButtonEnabled { get { return _stepCounter == 5 ? false : true; } }

private ICommand _previousStepButtonCommand;
public ICommand PreviousStepButtonCommand
{
    get { return _previousStepButtonCommand?? (_previousStepButtonCommand= new RelayCommand(PerviousStepButton);}
}

public void PerviousStepButton()
{
   _stepCounter--;
}

public bool PreviousStepButtonEnabled { get { return _stepCounter == 0 ? false : true; } }
```

Comment: What's the need for `NextStepButtonEnabled`/`PreviousStepButtonEnabled` props? Why just don't use `ICommand.CanExecute`?

Comment: He is new to MVVM, so I thought this will be less complex to him. I always use ICommand.Execute in my code,